# Cascading persistence in MongooseJS

Tags: mongoose

Does MongooseJS have any support for cascading persistence, either directly or through plugins?

The following will add the `foo` document to the database in the collection `foos` as well as save the document `wrap` correctly:

```
var fooSchema  = new Schema({ name: String, value: Number }),
    fooModel   = mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema),
    wrapSchema = new Schema({ name: String, item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId } }),
    wrapModel  = mongoose.model('FooWrap', wrapSchema);

var foo = new fooModel({ name: 'First', value: 1 });
foo.save(function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var wrap = new wrapModel({ name: 'Foo Wrapper', item: data });
  wrap.save(function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    ...
  });
});
```

As far as I understand it, this approach is the correct approach. As Mongoose and MongoDB require you to save your documents independently.

As such, the following code fails to add `bar` to a `bars` collection, but saves `wrap` with `bar`'s `_id`. There is a `barwraps` collection, but no `bars` collection.

```
var barSchema  = new Schema({ name: String, value: Number }),
    barModel   = mongoose.model('Bar', barSchema),
    wrapSchema = new Schema({ name: String, item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId } }),
    wrapModel  = mongoose.model('BarWrap', wrapSchema),
    bar        = new barModel({ name: 'Second', value: 1 }),
    wrap       = new wrapModel({
      name: 'Bar Wrapper',
      item: bar
    });
wrap.save(function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  ...
});
```

Is it possible, or more accurately advisable, to make the second case perform a cascading save operation using middleware `pre` hooks on save?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save `bar` object to `wrapModel` and then, use its ObjectId in `wrap`.